# hook_menu not working with alias

Tags: 7, hooks

I have a hook_menu:

```
$items['node/%/tokens/%api_token'] = array(
    'title' => 'View an API Call',
    'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form',
    'page arguments' => array('api_token_edit', 1, 3),
    'access arguments' => array('edit own profile'),
    'type' => MENU_LOCAL_TASK,
);
```

When visiting url: `node/1229/tokens/1`, it works as expected.

When visiting the friendly alias: `mypage/tokens/1`, it gives me a 404.

Why is this? I thought `hook_menu` used the internal arguments?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That behavior is not inclued in core. You can try this two modules:

- [Sub-pathauto (Sub-path URL Aliases)](https://www.drupal.org/project/subpathauto): The Drupal Path module matches only full URLs when creating SEO-friendly aliases. This module extends that behavior by also matching known sub-paths and replacing them with their respective alias.
- [Extended Path Aliases](https://www.drupal.org/project/path_alias_xt): SImilar to previous module, but includes more functionlaity. The drawback is that it needs core patching (adding a line to nclude/path.inc) or installing PECL runkit library.

Comment: Awesome! I actually have Sub-pathauto enabled already (but only 1 deep). It didn't occur to me that could be an issue. I made it 2 deep and eureka! :) Thank you for this, it's been bugging me for hours.